# Is it better for SEO to use alt text or "screen reader only" text to describe an image that has text on it?

Tags: seo, images, accessibility, alt-attribute

Whenever possible I try to turn images that have text on them into html/css to separate the textual content from the image for better responsiveness and SEO. However, sometimes this cannot be done as a client might explicitly request to use the image.

In these cases, is it better to write the text that is on the image in the image's `alt` attribute, or write it inside of a [screen reader only](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/screen-readers/) class? Or both? I'd assume not both as this would read twice to a screen reader (once in the alt attribute and once in the `sr-only` class).

Both would get indexed by Google I assume either way, but I'm wondering if there's benefits / drawbacks to either option.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly i don't see how to utilize `sr-only` for your purpose. But adding the text to both of `alt` and `title` attributes (`<img src="" alt="your content" title="your content"`) will finally do the job.

Comment: So what I meant was let's say there is an image that a client would like to use as a heading, where the heading text of the `<article>` is on the actual image. In that case, I could either use `sr-only` to write the title after the `<img />` tag, or just use the alt attribute.